# Remove last comma from this query

Tags: query

I'm having trouble fixing this for working in ie8, i find out thats last comma is problem, but dont know how to fix it.

this is current code.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'katalog', 'posts_per_page' => 999 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ($loop->have_posts()) : 
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php global $post; $thumb=wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full'); $thumb2=wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium'); $url = rwmb_meta( 'smb_katalozi' ); ?>
{image : "<?php echo $thumb[0] ?> ", title : "<?php echo get_the_title() ?>", url : "<?php echo post_permalink( $url ); ?>"},

<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

and the output is this

```
{image : "img url", title : "title", url : "url"},
{image : "img url", title : "title", url : "url"},
```

and i want it to be

```
{image : "img url", title : "title", url : "url"},
{image : "img url", title : "title", url : "url"}
```

so, its different just by last comma.

---

Got it to work with this code

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'katalog', 'posts_per_page' => 999 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    $post_count = 0;
    $te = $loop->post_count;
    $total = $te-1;
    if ($loop->have_posts()) : 
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $post;  $thumb=wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full'); $thumb2=wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium'); $url = rwmb_meta( 'smb_katalozi' );
    if ($post_count == 0 || $post_count !== $total) { ?>
        {image : "<?php echo $thumb[0] ?> ", title : "<?php echo get_the_title() ?>", url : "<?php echo post_permalink( $url ); ?>"},
    <?php } if ($post_count == $total) { ?>
        {image : "<?php echo $thumb[0] ?> ", title : "<?php echo get_the_title() ?>", url : "<?php echo post_permalink( $url ); ?>"}
    <?php }
    $post_count++;
    endwhile; else: endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: Got it to work with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to build up some JSON. Why not use what PHP already provides, which has the advantage of escaping characters too?

```
global $post;

$data = array();

if ($loop->have_posts()) {
    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $thumb=wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full');
        $thumb2=wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
        $url = rwmb_meta( 'smb_katalozi' );

        $data[] = array (
            'image' => $thumb[0],
            'title' => get_the_title(),
            'url' => post_permalink( $url )
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of comma inside `while` loop:

```
if ( $loop->have_posts() )
    echo ',';
```

This will output comma as long as there is still next post in loop.

Comment: you sure? This should be in the while loop to iterate.

Comment: I meant this to go inside loop, where plain text comma currently is.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem? Greetings from the _Low Quality_ queue. :)

Comment: @toscho hey, I spent a lot of effort twisting this into WP-specific answer already :)

Comment: tips and tricks... is it such a big deal? ^^ I prefer using CSS for separators, indeed it's poor.

Answer (score -1):

While this can be done in PHP, I prefer using some markup and css peudo-class such as [last-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)

So this can be :

```
<span class="last-child">{image : "<?php echo $thumb[0] ?> ", title : "<?php echo get_the_title() ?>", url : "<?php echo post_permalink( $url ); ?>"}</span>
```

and in your stylesheet :

```
.last-child:after { content:", "; }
.last-child:last-child:after { content:"";}
```

You can use [selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/) to make it compatible with older versions on IE